# c# regex for awkward mail and phone number

Tags: c#, regex

I've used the following 2 regex, that I have found here:

1. for 10 digit phone number with space before and after it:  `@"(?<!\d)\d{10}(?!\d)"`
2. For email:

> ```
> @"(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@"
>                    + @"((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?
> ```
>
> [0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])."
>                            + @"([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]).([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
>                          + @"([a-zA-Z]+[\w-]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})";

the email regex works fine for normal and correct email addresses,

but my input text isn't actually normal and correct, sau I have to introduce another particularity for it,  I would also like it to parse:

```
myname@this -email.com *or* myname@this- email.com *or* myname@this - email.com
```

And the 10 digit number phone regex only extracts the last 9 digits of the number, with the phone number starting with 0 :

for nr = 0123456789 I only get : 123456789 , the phone number is found in text like: 
`"some text here 0123456789 and some more here"`.

I've also found that the 10 digit number may be found in this form : `012/3456789`

Comment: Something to read before tackling this problem http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: Have a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses you will see that `!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}|~@example.org` is a valid address as well as `postbox@com` but they are not match with your regex.

Comment: The only way to validate an address is to send an email to that address. You could eventually test `[^@]+@[^@]+`

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't believe you need to use look ahead to match your phone number. You could do something like `" (\d[^0-9a-zA-Z]*?){9}\d "` to match for numbers exactly 10 digits long, with any kind of junk between the numbers (except a-z letters). Careful though, it would also match stuff like `" 012 à 3456789 "`. If the single slash is the only possible separator, you can use `" (\d/?){9}\d "`: no false positive but you wont match unexpected separators.
2. Regarding the email matter, the official complete regex is pretty long. Gusdor's link (http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) gives some context and a simple one that should match pretty much every email address actually in use. Tweaking it a little bit to match your case (`this   -domain.com` or `this- domain.org` would be matched), you could use something like this:

   ```
   [a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9]*( *?- *)?[a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
   ```

The custom part here is the `( *?- *)?` added to the right place.